# redirect second domain to static page

Tags: redirect, domain

I got a little problem. My client is a restaurant. I set up their site using WordPress. Now the client also started a catering business. So I created a static page for this subject in WordPress.

Of course with WordPress rewritten URLS it's now www.domain1.com/catering

Now my client ordered a second domain just for his catering business and wants to forward this domain to the static page. I tried linking via .htaccess to www.domain1.com/catering but this doesn't work of course, because it's no physical folder just a rewritten URL.

What's the right way for doing that?

Found a lot about redirecting in WordPress but nothing really gave me a simple answere i could follow. I would heavily appreciate you helping me out.

Cheers Andy

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to forward http://cateringdomain.com (a domain that exists in name only) to http://www.domain1.com/catering (a page that exists on your Wordpress installation)?

Comment: exactly, yes. Sorry if that is somewhat confusing. Tried to explain the best i could.

Comment: Have you tried linking to the permalink of the page?

Comment: yeah of course, doesnt work. that's my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to get it to work in some other way.

It's normal it doesn't work, since the url from the page can't be changed by the .htaccess, because the url is not your permalink but the new domain.

Why not set the name server of the new url, to the old one. 
so they go to the same page. 
Then change your .htaccess, accordingly to change to your internal wordpress link when the website is visited from the new domain. That should work.

If you don't find how to change your .htaccess file accordingly let me know I can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that claims to do *(we haven't tried it ourselves)* what you are looking for.

It is called [Domain Mapping System](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/domain-mapping-system/).

***From the plugin's description:***

> *"Domain Mapping System allows to map domains to WP pages and/or custom types."*
>
> ...Imagine you've got a company website based on wordpress with the
>   domain www.mycompany.com, all good so far. Furthermore, you've got two
>   products with own domains, e.g. www.myregularproduct.com and
>   www.myspecialproduct.com....

In case you haven't figured a way yet, give it a try and let us know how it goes.